# JSON-driven iOS MVC architecture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller

I know this is a bit of an ethereal question, but I'm working on an app that takes its entire structure from a remote JSON object and I'm trying to figure out the best way to approach the creation of Views, View Controllers, and Models.  Currently, I am using RestKit to grab, parse, and map objects. I will have the structure of the views, controls, and fields defined at runtime, so how should I dynamically create and manage object composition, view controllers, and all appropriate delegates? *(I imagine KVC and KVO will have a huge part in all of this.)*

### A few things to address:

- **Nested/chained delegation** to allow leaf control events to bubble up to the root controller and then down to the proper model.
- **Dynamic object composition** to allow a view to contain an arbitrary combination of subviews at runtime
- **Dynamically linking data** between views and the proper model objects

Are there any good resources, guides, or examples of implementing/planning for this type of architecture?

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not satisfy you but i will try to help.

Initialize dictionaries(NSDictionary) and detecet objects&values with `[yourObject objectForKey:@"yourJSONKey"];` and `[yourKey valueForKey:@"yourJSONValue"];` and after this create&push your views so that thay play a rol in run time(according to the JSON response)